# Accidentally pulled fruit spurs during harvest

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, harvesting, cherries

I was harvesting cherries and wasn't aware until after that I should NOT pull off the fruit spurs.

I harvested quite a bit. I feel bad. Is the damage permanent? Will they grow back?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, they will grow back. If you pulled off a good percentage of them, the tree may not produce as much next year, but the year after it will be fine.

The damage isn't permanent, and if you only pulled the very ends off the spurs, they may even grow back this year.

Comment: J.Musser...doesn't pruning off a lot of these spurs produce less but better fruit?

Comment: @stormy Well, if done properly it can, but if you pull them off of the whole area on one side of the plant, and leave them all on in another, you won't much see that effect.